# HTML 5 video background on mobile

Tags: html

I am trying to make a video my background, which will loop. It works perfectly on PC, but once I test it on mobile (`IOS`) it doesn't appear.

I've tried putting `playsinline` and making the the video path `absolute`, but it it still doesn't work on mobile.

**HTML**

```
<video autoplay muted loop playsinline id="myVideo">
    <source src="vhs.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Note: What could be an alternative to having a video be the background?

I initially wanted the same video, but in `.gif` format. However, it was not nice.

Comment: What iOS version are you using? Your code should works.

Comment: I am using iOS 10. I have tried on safari, opera and chrome for IOS. None of those browsers work.

Comment: Well they all use the Safari engine iirc on iOs. ;)

Comment: Do you have any warning / error on your iOS web inspector?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be giving any warnings or errors. Is there maybe another element I can use in place of this? Maybe object?

Comment: @RickyNotaro-Garcia Opera and Chrome have not been webkit browsers for several years now.